# issues with cron file in cron.d

Tags: cron

running amazon ami (similar to centos.)

this is what I found on cron file under /var/log  :

```
Sep  4 15:32:01 mike crond[2289]: (root) BAD FILE MODE (/etc/cron.d/mytasks)
```

and this is my file mytasks its under the folder cron.d

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=mygmailemail
HOME=/
#hourly query for social share data
1  1-23  *  *  *  wget -q http://localhost/sharecounter.php?period=hourly -O /dev/null 2      >&1 > /dev/null

#daily query for social share data
1  0  * *   1-6  wget -q http://localhost/sharecounter.php?period=daily -O /dev/null         2>&1 > /dev/null
```

any ideas on what is wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the message told you, the permissions of the file are wrong. You have probably made it group or world writable; if this is the case, it is a security risk and crond will refuse to run it.

Comment: perfect thanks Michael. I changed the permission to 0777 it was 0644

Comment: Right, once you fix that then it should run again.